# Ui Elements disappearing in Xcode 7.0

Tags: xcode, user-interface, element

im facing one problem in Xcode wich seems to be caused by a bug in Xcode itself.
Some UI elements disappear in my program after i run it. All the elements are still visible in storyboard but not in my running program.
After ≈20 running tests it appears again.
Do you know something about this issue?

Comment: Are you using constraints on the elements in Storyboard?

Comment: at the time i did not. But i figured out how i can "fix" it. After rearranging the view layers the element appears again.